# Why is listFiles() method returning null?

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm wondering why the listFiles() method is returning null?  I am using the this string for a file path: /storage/UsbDriveA.

Here is the code I'm currently using:

```
List<String> filesInFlashDrive = addListOfFiles("/storage/UsbDriveA/");

public ArrayList<String> addListOfFiles(String directoryPath) {
    File f = new File(directoryPath);
    f.mkdirs();
    Log.i("FileBrowserActivity", "File Value:" + f);
    Log.i("FileBrowserActivity", "List of files:"+f.listFiles());
    File[] file = f.listFiles();
    /*File[] file = f.listFiles(new FileFilter() {
        @Override
        public boolean accept(File pathname) {
            return pathname.toString().endsWith(".pdf") ? true : false;
        }
    });*/
    ArrayList<String> arrayFiles = new ArrayList<String>();
    if (file.length == 0)
        return null;
    else {
        for (int i=0; i<file.length; i++)
            arrayFiles.add(file[i].getName());
    }

    return arrayFiles;
}
```

Why is the listFiles() method returning null?

Comment: `I am using the this string for a file path: /storage/UsbDriveA.` probably, that path does not exist.

Comment: I checked to make sure it exists and it does when I plugin the USB drive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, your device or emulator may not have such a path. Very few devices do.

Second, because that appears to be [removable storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/09/storage-situation-removable-storage.html), you do not have arbitrary filesystem access to it on Android 4.4+ devices.

Comment: I double checked to make sure that I have that path on my phone that I'm testing on and I do.

Comment: @CommonsWare So is there any way to read that removable sdcard or usb drive. I am successfully get the path like "0DEF-1813" dynamically (not hard coded). When I check, isFile, isDirectory, canRead returns false. listFiles return null even files anre folders are there in removable SDCard. Allow read & write permission. Any other permission do we have to grant ?

Comment: @Smeet: "So is there any way to read that removable sdcard or usb drive" -- not via filesystem APIs. Use the Storage Access Framework (e.g., `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE`) and `DocumentFile`.

Comment: @CommonsWare I didn't try  it for this but will give a try and update you. There must be some way for the same as one explorer from play store able to list all files and folders. All other file explorer is failed to do so.